# Jenkins as service user on OSX running IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin.ios, jenkins, ios-simulator

We are running Jenkins on an OSX server as a service user.  The Jenkins user is restricted (not able to log in) because the server is accessible to the outside world.

We are running unit tests in the IOS Simulator.  However, the simulator will start, but not run the app.  I believe this is because Jenkins' user does not have UI access/permissions because we can run the app when logged in with users directly on the machine with UI.

Is there a way to add permissions to Jenkins user that will allow the IOS Simulator to run with UI without compromising security?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Jenkins as a daemon service? If so, it won't be able to interact with UI, see [launchd man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html)

I ran into the same problem before when trying to perform UI Automation, so I configured Jenkins as launch agent of a user, then I could run UI test from Jenkins as that user.

For security, maybe you can setup access control on Jenkins see [Standard Security Setup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup)